# Nuget Telnet v0.6.0 Does not support Framework DNXCore, Ver5.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I just created a new MVC 6 App.  I used Nuget to install Telnet. Then built the project.  I get an error that Telnet does not support DNXCore. I have seen other posts where people target other .net versions. Can anyone show me how to do this or make Telnet work?  I am new to MVC6 so, I see it is fine in DNX 4.5.1. IS this just an issue the Telnet developer needs to fix?

Here is the Project.Jason it created, from VS 2015 SP1 with All MVC updates.

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebServerManager-8ce24b02-fbae-4228-9f7d-6b4bcec6833a",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Telnet": "0.6.0"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/13/dnx-framework-choices-and-asp-net-5.aspx

The post above really helped me understand this. I had to remove the dependency on DNXCore. I deleted it from the project.json

[image]

dnx46 = full .net

dnxcore50 = DNXCore

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx46": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```